# How Salt and Pepper, Minced Chili Garlic INTO frozen lobster meat? How get 椒鹽 into 龍蝦?

Tags: lobster

I want cook at home O Mei Restaurant in Richmond Hill's ["Deep fry body and head with spiced peppered salt and minced chili garlic".](https://www.chowhound.com/post/omei-giant-lobster-11lbs-4-ways-photos-873273)  But  I don't want [deep fry](https://youtu.be/9tgXpncpmpc?t=41) for health. I can pan fry  with sun flower oil.

[image]

But I use frozen lobster meat. How flavor [spiced peppered salt and minced chili garlic](https://andrewzimmern.com/recipes/fu-xian-style-crispy-salt-and-pepper-lobster/) INTO lobster meat? In Chinese, how I stuff 椒鹽 into 龍蝦? I want taste spiced peppered salt and minced chili garlic! Not enough just sprinkle spiced peppered salt and minced chili garlic in wok with lobster!!!

[image]

Comment: Let me see if I understood you right: You want to make a battered, deep-fried dish without deep-frying, using different ingredients and expect a comparable outcome? To me, this is akin to trying to replicate an oil painting with felt pens. The results may be good, but certainly not like the original.

Comment: And as a mod: Please stop the excessive use of links and pictures, make your question clearer and on point and less cluttered.

Comment: @Stephie "battered, deep-fried dish without deep-frying". Well...I can pan fry. Just want try this at home. "different ingredients" ...no? we both use lobsters? mine just frozen. and sorry! picture is thousand words. easier to see what i try do?

Comment: Pamela, you may have noticed that your post wasn’t too well received so far. I was trying to help. The upvotes on my comments indicate that I am apparently not the only user who sees it that way. There’s a fine line between helpful and cluttered, one picture or three of basically the same thing, helpful or distracting. I still struggle to understand what _exactly_ your question is.

Comment: @stephie thanks much for trying to help! i know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flavour profile of "pepper salt" (椒鹽) is generally a combination of Chinese five-spice (五香粉), garlic, and chilli. Restaurants first deep-fry the protein (lobster, squid, fish, etc.) then combine it with everything else in a wok.

However, your problem seems to be that there isn't enough flavour in your version, which really doesn't have much to do with whether it's deep-fried or not. You could try:

- Simply adding more seasoned salt/garlic/chilli to taste
- Marinating your lobster in a combination of Chinese cooking wine, salt, and sugar  for ~30 minutes
- Frying your minced garlic and chilli with five-spice powder for longer, blooming the spices and flavouring the oil
- Before pan-frying, coat your lobster in seasoned cornstarch for flavour and to help it crisp up